# Responsive CSS transform for before pseudo-element

Tags: css, rotation, transform, pseudo-element

The effect I am after here is to show the word "Introducing" in the before pseudo element for an h1 header that has its own content centered.  My effort thus far is shown below

```css
h1::before
{
 font-size:0.7rem;
 content:'Introducing';
 position:absolute;
 left:calc(50% - 6em);
 top:-0.75em;
 transform:rotate(-45deg);   
  
}
h1
{
 text-align:center;
 position:relative;
 margin-top:30px;
}
```

```html
<h1>
Hello
</h1>
```

This works and, as far as I can tell, is responsive - the before pseudo retains its placement relative to its parent.  However, I suspect that this is not the right solution.  Hopefully, someone here can suggest a better way.

Comment: Maybe a better place would be https://codereview.stackexchange.com/?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current solution is responsive about different screen sizes, but it isn't about different h1 lengths. A longer text will need a different position.

You can solve it make the width of h1 adjust to its content. And now, just position the pseudo on the upper left, center it with a translation and rotate it.

```css
h1::before {
  font-size: 0.7rem;
  content: 'Introducing';
  position: absolute;
  top: -1em;
  transform: translateX(-50%) rotate(-45deg);
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  margin: 30px auto;
  width: fit-content;
  background-color: cadetblue;
}
```

```html
<h1>
  Hello
</h1>
<h1>
  Hello World
</h1>
```